# CKEditor remove my title attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor

I use CKEditor for forms creation and I need set `name` and `title` attributed in any of form controls like `<input>`, `<select>` and `<textarea>` for future processing.

Q1: when I create `title` attr in source view and return to result view this title attr is disappeared. How can I hold it?

Q2: can I add `title` option to CKEditor dialog forms when I create new elements from toolbar (where I can set `name` attr etc.)?

Comment: Q1: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter

Comment: Ok, I have read that and what? How can I do that?

Comment: Just set CKEDITOR.config.allowedContent to true or create your own ACL rules. What the mighty Reinmar was aiming at is that ACL is most likely stripping your unsupported title attribute. There is not simple way of adding a title option, you would need to edit the CKE source (maintenance issues) or create your own plugin (much work) OR hack a new element there during runtime (even more work, will not give example).